# split a paragraph in word to two paragraphs using OpenXml SDK?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a method that splits paragraphs into two paragraphs at the same location on the word file.
the logic is working fine but I'm losing the document format and styles.

```
foreach (Paragraph p in body.Descendants<Paragraph>())
{
//splitting the paragraph
 var part2 = p.InnerText.Substring(startIndex);
 var part1 = p.InnerText.Substring(0, startIndex);
 p.InnerText.Replace(p.InnerText, part1);
 p.InnerText.Replace(p.InnerText, part2);
 pargs.Add(part1);
 pargs.Add(part2);
}
// clean the documetn 
body.RemoveAllChildren<Paragraph>();
//re-creat the paragraphs 
for (int i = 0; i < pargs.Count; i++)
{
   Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
   Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
   run.AppendChild(new Text(pargs[i]));
}
   
   return paras;
```

above is simplified code
I know that my approach is the cause for this problem since I'm taking the inner text of each paragraph and creating a new paragraph without taking the styles. my question is. is there another approach

Comment: not answer but a few comments to make your question shorter: 1. remove task stuff 2.user regex, instead of regex+string split 3. or just use some hardcoded strings to make the code even shorter.

Comment: If you don't already have it, you may want to download/install the [OpenXml Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5).

Comment: I made the changes, I think the question is more readable now

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the original style, you can just copy run properties and set them in newly created Run.
Something like that (haven't tested though):

```cs
var properties = paragraph
                    .Descendants<Run>()
                    .First()
                    .RunProperties
                    .Clone();
...
var run = newParagraph.AppendChild(new Run()
{
  RunProperties = (RunProperties)properties
});
```

Comment: I tried this code but nothing happened, when I debug this line of code it's telling me that the element is empty, I also tried to copy the inner XML but the same result